# match regular expression - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I have the following url:

```
var oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
```

I want to take username and token out of it;

I tried:

```
var match = (/#\{(.*?)\}/g.exec(oURL));
console.log(match);
```

but it is giving me:

```
["#{username}", "username", index: 27, input: "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}"
```

Why isn't catching token?

Thanks

Comment: *"Why isn't catching token?"* What do you mean by *token*? It may help to show what you expect.

Comment: In the result set match[1] = "username" but how about my other matches "token"?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I thought you were talking about some token of the username.

Comment: I expect "username" and "token"; in other owrds matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) only returns the first match from the given index whenever called.

> #### Returns
>
> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured.
>
> If the match fails, the `exec()` method returns null.

You would need to loop, continuously matching again to find all the matches.

```js
var matches = [],
match,
regex = /#\{(.*?)\}/g,
oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
while (match = regex.exec(oURL)) {
    matches.push(match)
}
console.log(matches)
```

However, if you are only interested in the first capture group, you can only add those to the matches array:

```js
var matches = [],
match,
regex = /#\{(.*?)\}/g,
oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
while (match = regex.exec(oURL)) {
    matches.push(match[1])
}
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: It shouldn't be matches.push(match[1])? Please correct it and I will mark it as solved! Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @Pasargad Sure, if you want just the first capture group.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

`oURL.match(/#\{(.*?)\}/g)`

Comment: I had already tried that it returns ["#{username}", "#{token}"] I want "username" and "token" instead

Comment: If you choose this option, you could `splice()` the string to return only the part of the string that you want.

Comment: `string.match` does not return capture groups if it includes the `g` flag. It's weird, but that's how it works. It just returns multiple matches in the string. Without the `g` flag `string.match` returns the same result as `regexp.exec`. Then to top off the JS weirdness `regexp.exec` won't return multiple capture groups as a single result, even with the `g` flag. It does however, update the lastMatchIndex property of the expression so you can match against the string in a loop and pull out all the capture group contents.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you accepted is perfect, but I thought I'd also add that it's pretty easy to create a little helper function like this:

```
function getMatches(str, expr) {
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = expr.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
  }
  return matches;
}
```

Then you can use it a little more intuitively.

```
var oURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{username}/posts?access_token=#{token}";
var expr = /#\{([^\{]*)?\}/g;
var result = getMatches(oURL, expr);
console.log(result);
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/VLyaeG

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var match = (/#\{(.*?)\}.*?#\{(.*?)\}/g.exec(oURL));
```